# Error during updating List of entity. EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have projects, which contains 2 aggregate entities (Person and WorkExperience) in Domain layer. For dbContext I created 2 entities with almost same properties and map them with automapper. Person  contains List of WorkExperiences. So, when I'm using automapper to update the found Person with 1 added WorkExperience it mappes well. But when I save changes EntityFrameworkCore throws Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException

The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

The solution is to add WorkExperience with it DbSet. BUT task want WorkExperiences be controlled only by Person's List of WorkExperience. References one to many configurated in fluent api.

Code. (Very simple)

```
public class PersonDb
{
    [Key]
    [Column("person_id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public List<WorkExperienceDb> WorkExperiences { get; set; }
}
public class WorkExperienceDb
{
    public PersonDb Person { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Person))]
    [Column("person_id")]
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("work_experience_id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
public async Task<Guid> AddWorkExperienceAsync(Guid personId, WorkExperienceDto workExperienceDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var person = await _repository.GetPersonAsync(personId, cancellationToken);

// Method of Aggregate Person
        person.SaveWorkExperience(
            workExperienceDto.Id,
            workExperienceDto.Position,
            workExperienceDto.Organisation,
            new Address(workExperienceDto.City, workExperienceDto.Country),
            workExperienceDto.Description,
            workExperienceDto.HireDate,
            workExperienceDto.FireDate);

        await _repository.UpdatePersonAsync(person, cancellationToken);

        await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        return workExperienceDto.Id;
    }
public async Task UpdatePersonAsync(Person person, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var entity = await _dbContext.Persons
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => Equals(p.Id, person.Id), cancellationToken);

        _mapper.Map(person, entity); // entity at this moment has 1 more workExperience in its List
    }
// Mapping Profile
CreateMap<Person, PersonDb>()
            .ForMember(personDb => personDb.Id,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(person => person.Id))
            .ForMember(personDb => personDb.FirstName,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(person => person.PersonFullName.FirstName))
            .ForMember(personDb => personDb.LastName,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(person => person.PersonFullName.LastName))
            .ForMember(personDb => personDb.Patronymic,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(person => person.PersonFullName.Patronymic))
            .ForMember(personDb => personDb.Email,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(person => person.Email.Value))
            .ForMember(personDb => personDb.Phone,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(person => person.Phone.Value))
            .ForMember(personDb => personDb.Avatar,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(person => person.Avatar))
            .ForMember(personDb => personDb.Remarks,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(person => person.Remarks))
            .ForMember(personDb => personDb.Gender,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(person => person.Gender))
            .ForMember(personDb => personDb.WorkExperiences,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(person => person.GetWorkExperiences()))
            .AfterMap((person, personDb) =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < personDb.WorkExperiences.Count; i++)
                {
                    personDb.WorkExperiences[i].PersonId = person.Id;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Why such overcomplicated code? EF Core doesn't need AutoMapper, extra "repository" or aliasing `SaveChanges`. A DbContext already is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work and Repository. AutoMapper is meant to map objects, not create UPDATE clauses. There's far more code that's working on the *wrong* objects here thatn would be needed to just update an entity

Comment: If you wanted to add WorkExperience to a person you'd only need to load that person, eg with `_dbContext.Persons.Find(personId)` and then add the items, eg with `person.WorkExperienses.AddRange(jobs);`. After that, `_dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();` will save everything. In the [EF Core - Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli#create-read-update--delete) example nothing special is done to add a `Post` to `Blog.Posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating entity graphs (entities and child sets) you generally need to handle the children collection separately, as well as consider what kinds of operations might take place in relation to the children. For instance, could a child be added, removed, replaced, and/or updated?

The first step would be ensuring that the child set is retrieved from the DB along with the parent:

```
    var entity = await _dbContext.Persons
        .Include(p => p.WorkExperiences)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => Equals(p.Id, person.Id), cancellationToken);
```

The next step depends on whether we could be looking at adds, removes, replacements (add+remove), or edits.

Edits mean looking at the matching records from both the DTO and DB state, finding the associated records and copying the values across. Automapper has a Map call that can help here:

```
var workExperiences = person.GetWorkExperiences();

foreach(var workExperience in workExperiences)
{
    var workExperienceDb = personDb.WorkExperiences.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == workExperienceId);
    if (workExperienceDb == null) continue;

    Mapper.Map(workExperience, workExperienceDb);
}
```

This checks for matching items between the DTO and DB and Mapper.Map will copy the allowed/configured values from the DTO to the DB entity if one is found.

For adds this will depend on whether work experiences are associations to existing data records, or owned in the sense that these additions would constitute new records. If WorkExperiences can be added as new records then these should be identifiable based on a placeholder default ID (I.e. 0) and can be mapped to new WorkExperience entities using Automapper and added to the personDb.WorkExperiences:

```
var newWorkExperienceDbs = workExperiences
    .Where(w => w.IsNew) // I.e. Id == 0, etc.
    .Select(w => Mapper.Map<WorkExperience>(w))
    .ToList();
if (newWorkExperienceDbs.Any())
    personDb.AddRange(newWorkExperienceDbs);
```

If instead we are dealing with associations, then we need to get the new Ids to associate, load them from the DB, and associate them. If we just were to Map them from the DTO these would constitute new references that the EF DbContext would expect to insert, resulting in errors or duplicate data. This also covers handling work experiences we may have deleted, so I'll include handling Deletes in the example below. If we aren't adding by association (instead using the above logic for adds) then ignore the Add logic below and just use the Deletes:

```
var workExperiences = person.GetWorkExperiences();
var updatedWorkExperienceIds = workExperiences
    .Select(w => w.Id)
    .ToList();
var existingWorkExperienceIds = personDb.WorkExperiences
    .Select(w => w.Id)
    .ToList();

var IdsToAdd = updatedWorkExperienceIds.Except(existingWorkExperienceIds);
var IdsToRemove = existingWorkExperienceIds.Except(updatedWorkExperienceIds);

if(IdsToRemove.Any())
{
    var workExperiencesToRemove = personDb.WorkExperiences
        .Where(w => IdsToRemove.Contains(w.Id))
        .ToList();
    personDb.WorkExperiences.RemoveRange(workExperiencesToRemove);
}
if (IdsToAdd.Any())
{
    var workExperiencesToAdd = _dbContext.WorkExperiences
        .Where(w => IdsToAdd.Contains(w.Id))
        .ToList();
    personDb.WorkExperiences.AddRange(workExperiencesToAdd);
}
```

I suspect that from your description and not wanting/needing a WorkExperiences `DbSet` in your `DbContext` that any add operation would constitute a new WorkExperience entity owned solely by that Person rather than associations, so you'd likely just need to consider the Delete scenario from the above example. Still, in cases where you are dealing with associations, the above should give you some ideas on how to manage them.

Comment: Why is it so complicated? Why EF core does not track changes in related collection? After Map from person to entity, entity contains 1 more WorkExperience with all parameters. BUT I've been looking into the ChangeTracker and it does not find any new WorkExperience. Why is that?

Comment: @KKKAndor it's not so complicated. EF does track changes in related collections. It doesn't load them automatically unless you tell it though, either with `Include` or by configuring the relation to load eagerly. When you call `Map` you produce completely new objects unrelated to EF. The problem is caused by the "repository" code you posted, not EF

Comment: It does not work with Include. When I call Map I'm telling to map all properties from sent person to found entity. So it changes found entity.

Comment: Automapper can help, but it's not a magician that can read intent when handed an object graph. Copying entire graphs of relations does require some deliberate code to ensure that the logic works out what has changed vs. been added vs. been removed. To put it simply if Automapper is handed 2 entities that have sets of children, how is it to assume which child in one reference correlates to which in the other? If they differ, are they in the same order where one was removed and replaced? It appears complicated because there is more to the problem than what you see on the surface.